# Get json array output from php in javascript and detect if it's undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, element

I'm attempting to retrieve json output from a php file and output a value. Can someone enlighten me on how to detect if the value is undefined and how to access one of the values in the array?

```
php response:
{"myObj":[{"userid":"9000","name":"Foo"},{"userid":"1000","name":"Bar"}]}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'reply.php',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        if (xhr && xhr.overrideMimeType) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType('application/json;charset=utf-8');
        }
    },
    data: {
        "action": "getmyObj"
    },
    success: function (reply) {
    if (reply.myObj.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if (typeof reply.myObj[i].name === 'undefined') {
                console.log("Undefined");
            } else {
                alert(reply.myObj[i].name);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what error you are facing? you code seems correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could replace

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
```

with

```
for (i = 0; i < reply.myObj.length; i++){
```

this way it will iterate according to how many entries there are instead of static `3` times, then u probably won´t even have to check if prop is undefined (because it is for the third iteration)

the check for the property though should be as simple as:

```
if (!reply.myObj[i].name) {
    console.log("Undefined");
} else {
    alert(reply.myObj[i].name);
```

because of the mentioned above u can be sure that `reply.myObj[i]` is defined